# Toggle icons on an accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have built an accordion using html css and jQuery. It works well apart from the icons to show whether the tabs are open or closed. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IeuEA)

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
$('ul#accordion > li > a').click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            accordionSpan = $('#accordion > li > a span');

         if ($this.attr('class') != 'active'){
            accordionSpan.removeClass();
            accordionSpan.addClass('icon-arrow-up-6');
            $('#accordion li ul').slideUp(200);
            $this.next().slideDown(200);
            $('#accordion li a').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $this.children().addClass('icon-arrow-down-7');
         } else {
            $this.next().slideToggle(200);
            if($this.children().hasClass('icon-arrow-down-7')) {
                $this.children().removeClass('icon-arrow-down-7').addClass('icon-arrow-up-6');
            } else {
                $this.children().removeClass('icon-arrow-up-6').addClass('icon-arrow-down-7');
            }
         }
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I need the icon to be a '+' when closed and '-' when open.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('ul#accordion > li > a').click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        accordionSpan = $('#accordion > li > a span');
      $this.addClass('active'); /// you miss this line
     if ($this.attr('class') != 'active'){
        accordionSpan.removeClass();
        accordionSpan.addClass('icon-arrow-up-6');
        $('#accordion li ul').slideUp(200);
        $this.next().slideDown(200);
        $('#accordion li a').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.children().addClass('icon-arrow-down-7');
     } else {
        $this.next().slideToggle(200);
        if($this.children().hasClass('icon-arrow-down-7')) {
            $this.children().removeClass('icon-arrow-down-7').addClass('icon-arrow-up-6');
        } else {
            $this.children().removeClass('icon-arrow-up-6').addClass('icon-arrow-down-7');
        }
     }
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Great. Now I need it to only open a single tab at a time, for example clicked tab opens and the rest close

Comment: Nice, two things I noticed with your method, what does the collapse class do? And is the content area dependent on a height?

Comment: its not dependent on a height 
 see this http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/3R2Jd/7/ you can stand what collapse class do

Answer (score 0):

Best way: 
add class to both images for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".one").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<img class="one" src="">+</img>
<img class="one" src="" style="display:none">-</img>
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>
```

now give display: none to "-" image which means "-" image will be hidden first and after click "-" image will be displayed in place of "+" image,

You can use

tag in place of  it will work, thanks